# Implement singleton pattern without using a private reference in java?

Tags: java, oop, object, singleton, private

This was asked in a recent discussion, but was not able to tackle it properly. However I answered it by giving example of `Enum` but he was looking for some other way. Can you highlight the ways for which we can overcome above question?

Comment: to downvoter : kindly explain if you have proper understanding of question?

Comment: It's not the variable that has to be private, just the constructor.

Comment: @Stultuske but the variable MUST have eager instantiation or wont be a Singletton

Comment: I agree with @BhargavModi. This is a fair question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you would implement a `Singleton` with a `public` field :

```
public class Singleton {
      public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

      private Singleton() {}

}
```

Further reading on the pros and cons of this approach :

[Item 3](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3) from Joshua Bloch's Effective Java.

Comment: Please read my answer for an explanation of why this approach is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer?** 

Using a `private YourClass` constructor and a `public YourClass` variable with eager instantiation

**Long answer** 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

```
public class Singleton {
      public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    //^ public variable

      private Singleton() {}
    //^ private constructor
}
```

Comment: But the `getInstance()` method is returning an instance that is surely stored in a private static field. Because of that I'm not sure I really understand the OP's question.

Comment: @Sam check my edit... *surely stored in a private static field*? Why? You can make it public...

Comment: Ah, using eager instantiation, of course! I was imagining lazy instantiation, in which case a public field would obviously be problematic.

Comment: when it's public, the getInstance method is no longer needed, that's the only difference

Comment: Sure! I wont recommend this design... Also if variable is public you can delete the `getInstance()` method... but to follow design I would prefer to mantain it

Comment: Actually that gives me another thought, which is that a public field could still be used with lazy instantiation and a static constructor.

Comment: @JordiCastilla Why do you need a `getInstance` method when `INSTANCE` is `public`.

Comment: @JordiCastilla Downovte retracted!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea, but if you change the `private` variable to a `public` one, you will achieve your goal.  You probably should declare the variable as `final` as well to avoid surprises, but it is not strictly necessary, and doesn't make it a good idea (IMO).

For what it is worth, there is no way to implement a singleton that doesn't involve an explicit variable to hold the instance, or an `enum`.

---

Here is what Bloch has to say on the tradeoff between the public and private variable approaches:

> "One advantage of the factory-method approach is that it gives you the flexibility to change your mind about whether the class should be a singleton without changing its API. The factory method returns the sole instance but could easily be modified to return, say, a unique instance for each thread that invokes it. A second advantage, concerning generic types, is discussed in Item 27. Often neither of these advantages is relevant, and the final-field approach is simpler."

My argument is that *knowing* that you won't need to change your mind in the future involves a degree of prescience.

Or to put it another way, you can't *know* that: you can only predict that.  And your prediction can be wrong.  And if that prediction does turn out to be wrong, then you have to change every piece of code the accesses the singleton via the public variable.

Now if your codebase is small, then the amount of code you need to change is limited.  However, if your codebase is large, or if it is not all yours to change, then this this kind of of mistake can have serious consequences.

That is why it is a bad idea.